# UITableViewCell clear color delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two `UITableView`s, the first (`FirstViewController.h`) is the menus and the second (`SecondViewController.h`), the menuItems. My problem is when I make the cell from the second tableView `clearColor`, when I make a selection from the `FirstViewController`, the item on `SecondViewController` appear as delayed.

```
@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [_items addObject:@"Menu1"];
    [_items addObject:@"Menu2"];
    [_items addObject:@"Menu3"];
    [_items addObject:@"Menu4"];


    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:  [UIImage imageNamed:@"light.png"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_items count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSString *item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:item];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



    return cell;
}
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MenuItems"]) {

        SecondViewController *secondViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        _items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MenuItem 1", @"MenuItem 2", @"MenuItem 3", @"MenuItem 4", nil];
        [secondViewController setItems:_items];

    }
}
@end



//--------------------------------------------------------------------------


@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light.png"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(onClick_btnBack:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack;

}
-(IBAction)onClick_btnBack:(id)sender  {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_items count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:item];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

      return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: What do you mean with *as delayed*?

Comment: when i click in the first listView, appears in the second list instantaneously the cells from the first list.